# Create Directory and Copy files from different directory (shared location) in production using excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a production mapping where the folder does have more files to copy from one shared location to the other location.

Location A:
//www//fp/ser/prod/Parent_Folder/SNO_01/ORIGINAL/test1.pdf,test2.pdf,.....

Location B:
//www//fp/ser/prod/Child_Folder/SNO_01/

As you see the above challenge, need to work on 2 steps

1. Create an empty Folder as  in location B; under serial number "SNO_01" (which already exist)
2. Copy files from location A:/ORIGINAL/test1.pdf,test2.pdf,..... into location B: /REISSUE/

Please note: there are 100's of Serial numbers or folders are there in prod.

Reissue folder needs to create runtime for every serial number SNO_01, SNO_02....

I tried the below script,

```
Sub CreateFolderCopyFiles()
'Macro to copy all files

 Dim n As String, msg As String, d As Date
Dim fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fils = fso.GetFolder("D:\UKRR\Parent_Folder\& SNO_01 &\Original").Files

'Verify all files in the folder, check the modification date and then copy 
'to another folder (named Old)
For Each fil In fils
n = fil.Name
d = fil.DateLastModified
If d >= Date - 1 Then
    file = n
    'The following line is where the error occurs
    fso.CopyFile "D:\UKRR\Parent_Folder\& SNO_01 &\Original", 
"D:\UKRR\Child_Folder\\& SNO_01 &\Reissue"
'Reissue is the new Folder has to create while runtime

End If
Next fil

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to [create the folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/createfolder-method) before copying files to it

Comment: "there are 100's of Serial numbers" - do you have a list of those, or are you looping all subfolders under `//www//fp/ser/prod/Parent_Folder/` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateFolderCopyFiles()
'Macro to copy all files

 Dim n As String, msg As String, d As Date
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fils = fso.GetFolder("D:\UKRR\Parent_Folder\& SNO_01 &\Original").Files

'Verify all files in the folder, check the modification date and then copy 
'to another folder (named Old)
For Each fil In fils
n = fil.Name
d = fil.DateLastModified
If d >= Date - 1 Then
'added
On Error Resume Next
exist = fso.GetFolder ("D:\UKRR\Child_Folder\\& SNO_01 &\Reissue")
If Err Then fso.CreateFolder "D:\UKRR\Child_Folder\\& SNO_01 &\Reissue"
On Error Goto 0
'end
file = n
    'The following line is where the error occurs

fso.CopyFile "D:\UKRR\Parent_Folder\& SNO_01 &\Original\" & file, _ 'added
"D:\UKRR\Child_Folder\\& SNO_01 &\Reissue\" & file                  'added
'Reissue is the new Folder has to create while runtime

End If
Next fil

End Sub
```